# postgresql numeric type without trailing zeros

Tags: postgresql, numeric

When use  numeric type, for example like this `numeric(4,2)` and if store in him number `1.2`, at end of number are adding zeros for filling `scale` part right? that is result is `1.20`

There is possible to save "short" scale as "short"? that is  without adding zeros at end ?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't worry about extra space used for `scale` part.

According to [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html) values of numeric type saved without trailing zeroes:

> Numeric values are physically stored without any extra leading or
>   trailing zeroes. Thus, the declared precision and scale of a column
>   are maximums, not fixed allocations. (In this sense the numeric type
>   is more akin to varchar(n) than to char(n).) The actual storage
>   requirement is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus
>   three to eight bytes overhead.