# Is this the correct way to cast, round, and avg an object in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, rounding, average

***QUESTION***

How do I use `avg` and `round` to provide a decimal point in PostgreSQL?

What function do I need to convert a string to a decimal number?

***FUNCTIONS USED***

**1st function**

```
AVG(ratings.dating) AS scent_avg
```

**1st error**

```
Error: expected { scents_id: 1, scent_avg: 4.5 } response body, got { scents_id: 1, scent_avg: '4.5000000000000000' }
```

**2nd function**

```
ROUND(AVG(ratings.rating), 1) AS scent_avg
```

**2nd error**

```
Error: expected { scents_id: 1, scent_avg: 4.5 } response body, got { scents_id: 1, scent_avg: '4.5' }
```

**3rd function**

What function is used to convert a string to a number?

***EDIT***

Looks like I had a mental lapse. **sticky bit** clarified that int has no decimals! I removed the int bit from the original post.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: "...to provide an integer with a decimal point" -- What? integers don't have a fractional part, so a point makes no sense. Or how do you mean that?

Comment: @Gordon - Ditto. Added PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Mureinik - 4.5. But I should be able to use any number combination that results in an average, with a decimal rounded to the tenth.

Comment: @stick bit - Thanks! Silly mistake on my end.

Comment: So the result shall be a `numeric` value *without* insignificant zeroes? Or as formatted string (`text`)?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - The result should be numeric without insignificant zeroes. Rounded to the tenths decimal place.

Comment: I added solutions for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Formatted string

Use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to get a formatted string without insignificant zeroes (or padding blanks) - "rounded to the tenth decimal place" as you commented:

```
SELECT to_char(round(avg(ratings.rating), 10), 'FM999999999990.9999999999')
```

Note the one `0`. Typically you want that position in any case. Like for `0.3`. Add as many `9` as you want to allow digits. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/currentfunctions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE)

> `0` specifies a digit position that will always be printed, even if it
> contains a leading/trailing zero. `9` also specifies a digit position,
> but if it is a leading zero then it will be replaced by a space, while
> if it is a trailing zero and fill mode is specified then it will be deleted.

And [about the `FM` prefix:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE)

> fill mode (suppress leading zeroes and padding blanks)

#### Numeric value without insignificant trailing zeroes

Cast to `double precision` (`float8`) to get a numeric value without insignificant trailing zeroes. The cast trims insignificant zeroes. Generally, casting to a floating point number can introduce corner case rounding errors.

I had suggested more sophisticated solutions first, but since you are only interested in precision up to the tenth decimal place and `float8` is precise up to 15 fractional digits, the problem does not apply. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT)

> On all currently supported platforms, the `real` type has a range of
> around 1E-37 to 1E+37 with a precision of at least 6 decimal digits.
> The `double precision` type has a range of around 1E-307 to 1E+308 with
> a precision of at least 15 digits. Values that are too large or too
> small will cause an error. Rounding might take place if the precision
> of an input number is too high. Numbers too close to zero that are not
> representable as distinct from zero will cause an underflow error.

So just:

```
SELECT round(avg(ratings.rating), 10)::float8
```

Note that we cast *after* rounding, as the variant of [`round()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) accepting a number of decimal places only works for `numeric` (due to the inexact nature of internal storage of floating point numbers).

---

Inside Postgres, you wouldn't worry too much about those trailing zeroes. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)

> Numeric values are physically stored without any extra leading or
> trailing zeroes. Thus, the declared precision and scale of a column
> are maximums, not fixed allocations. (In this sense the numeric type
> is more akin to `varchar(n)` than to `char(n)`.) The actual storage
> requirement is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus
> three to eight bytes overhead.

See:

- [PostgreSQL adds trailing zeros to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920157/postgresql-adds-trailing-zeros-to-numeric)

Inside Postgres, equality is established correctly:

```
SELECT numeric '4.50000000' = numeric '4.5'  -- true
SELECT jsonb '{"scents_id": 4.5}' = jsonb '{"scents_id": 4.5000}'  -- true
```

Your client throwing the error seems to compare text representations, which is subtly incorrect. So you may have to format like your client expects ...

Comment: I see. Would you be able to explain this output?
`expected { scents_id: 1, scent_avg: 4.5 } response body, got { scents_id: 1, scent_avg: '4.5000000000000000' }`

Comment: @peyo: Your client program obviously compares *strings* (which seems subtly incorrect). When casting `numeric` to `text`, insignificant zeroes are preserved by default. You can get rid of those with `to_char()`, for instance, like demonstrated.

Comment: `Your client throwing the error seems to compare text representations, which is subtly incorrect. So you may have to format like your client expects ...` This helped me solve the issue. This is my endpoint test: `it("GET /scents/:id/ratings responds with 200 and the specified scent rating", () => {
      const id = 1;
      const expected = {
        scents_id: id,
        scent_avg: JSON.stringify(4.5)
      }
      return supertest(app)
        .get(`/scents/${id}/ratings`)
        .expect(200, expected)
    });` I added `JSON.stringify` around 4.5 and the test is passing.

Comment: Cool, we found the actual *root* of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, this should do the trick:

```
cast(avg(ratings.ratio * 1.0) as decimal(4, 1))
```

I don't see any rounding here.  `4.5` IS the average of `4` and `5` mathematically speaking.

Comment: Ultimately, there will be an indefinite number of ratings in the database, so I wanted to make sure it was rounding to the tenths place.

Comment: @peyo . . . Postgres rounds when converting to decimal.  Also in Postgres, the `* 1.0` is not needed.